# Apple Agenda totally empty and "updating" endlessly

Tags: macos, icloud, calendar, software-update

Yesterday my agenda suddenly froze (with the spinner showing for at least half an hour. So I did a force quit, and opened it again, and now it just shows this:

[image]

The line "Agenda's bijwerken..." translates as "Updating agendas".

It has shown this for hours now, so I don't think anything is going on anymore. Most importantly though, the whole agenda seems empty in the background (and I don't have iCloud backups from the agenda).

Does anybody know what I can do to A) get the events from my agenda back, in whichever form possible, and B) get the Agenda working again.

I'm pretty good on the command line, so messing around in system files won't be a problem for me. I just don't have a clue where to start. If it's important; I'm on OSX 10.11.2.

All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the reason why this is happening, but I had this once. I think it's connected somehow with error of synchronization, it just gets into loop, and never recovers back.

First of all, try to `Force Quit` for this app, and then to restart. In some cases it helps.

**Second scenario, if the previous one haven't helped to troubleshoot, is**:

1. Open up system Preferences and navigate to accounts `` > `System Preferences` > `Accounts`
2. Deactivate the iCloud. (try deselecting calendars, as well)
3. Restart iCal.

**If it haven't, then you need to clean the cache**. Instructions [described here](http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12386508) helped to restore:

1. Quit iCal/Calendar.
2. **Make backup** copies of these files before deleting them. (!important in case something goes wrong)
3. Delete the calendar cache found here:

   `~/Library/Calendars/Calendar Cache`

   `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.iCal` (if these files exist)

You may try the second scenario, provided by the link above, but in this case, **you will lose the not saved events**, which were not synced with your account. You additionally would need to do these actions:

4. Delete the Events directory found here:

   `~/Library/Calendars/*.calendar/Events`
5. Delete the application's preference files here:

   `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iCal.plist`

   `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iCal.helper.plist` (if this file exists)

And then to reconfigure the preferences and accounts.

Comment: @kramer65, have these instructions helped you?